# 2 Rows to 1 Row - Nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a  response column that stores 2 different values for a same product based on question 1 and question 2. That creates 2 rows for each product but I want only one row for each product. 
Example:

```
select Product, XNumber from MyTable where QuestionID IN ('Q1','Q2')
```

result shows:

```
Product  XNumber
Bat      abc
Bat      abc12
```

I want it to display like below:

```
Product    Xnumber1  Xnumber2
Bat        abc       abc12
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: this is a pivot table http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx  However, unless the rows will always be two, you must use dynamic SQL.  If it is constant you could use a case statement as well.

Comment: How do you get Xnumber1 and Xnumber2? What if there are more than two rows? PIVOT might do what you want, but there is more to this question than it seems.

Comment: How have you thought of implementing this? On the run or is the table suppose to be ready with those columns before the execution begins? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work best if you don't have answers for both Q1 and Q2 for all ids

```
SELECT a.Product, b.XNumber as XNumber1, c.XNumber as XNumber2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM MyTable) a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b ON a.Product = b.Product AND b.QuestionID = 'Q1'
LEFT JOIN MyTable c ON a.Product = c.Product AND c.QuestionID = 'Q2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have two different values you can try this:

```
SELECT a.Product, a.XNumber as XNumber1, b.XNumber as XNumber2
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b
ON a.Product = b.Product
WHERE a.QuestionId = 'Q1'
AND b.QuestionId = 'Q2'
```

I assume that XNumber1 is the result for Q1 and Xnumber2 is the result for Q2.

Comment: I already have 5 tables joined and your solution is a self-joining a table. It's complicated with other 5 tables but I will try and update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  SQL expects their to be a lot of joins.  Any solution using joins will be the fastest solution.

Comment: This query did not display any values in XNumber1 and XNumber2 column.

Comment: @Bulbul see my answer for the correct way to deal with missing values for some product IDs

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve your expected results.  However, it relies on knowing that only xNumber abc and abc12 are the values.  If this is not the case, then a dynamic pivot would be likely needed.

```
SELECT product, max(case when XNumber = 'abc' then xNumber end) as XNumber1, 
                max(Case when xNumber = 'abc12' then xNumber end) as xNumber2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Product
```

The problem is that SQL needs to know how many columns will be in the result at the time it compiles the SQL.  Since the number of columns could be dependent on the data itself (2 rows vs 5 rows) it can't complete the request.  Using Dynamic SQL you can find out the number of rows, then pass those values in as the column names which is why the dynamic SQL works.

Comment: No, XNumber values are not always abc and abc12. Q1 results the first row example abc and Q2 results the second row abc12. Now each products have 2 rows with different XNumber. Hope that clarifies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you two columns, the first will be the product, and the 2nd will be a comma delimited list of xNumbers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Product,
xNumbers = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT  ', ' + T1.XNumber 
                        FROM MyTable T1
                        WHERE t.Product = T1.Product
                        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')        
FROM MyTable T
```

To get what you want, we need to know how many columns there will be, what to name them, and how to determine which value goes into which column

Comment: I need three columns. 1) Product 2) XNumber1 3) XNumber2 . Currently XNumber1 and XNumber2 values are stored in one column XNumber. Can't use Distinct because this is part of the issue which I am summarizing.

Answer (score 0):

Been using `rank()` a lot in current code we have been working on at my day job.  So this fun variant came to mind for your solution.

Using rank to get the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd possible item identifier then grouping them to create a simulated `pivot`

`DECLARE @T TABLE (PRODUCT VARCHAR(50), XNumber VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
  ('Bat','0-12345-98765-6'),
  ('Bat','0-12345-98767-2'),
  ('Bat','0-12345-98768-1'),
  ('Ball','0-12345-98771-6'),
  ('Ball','0-12345-98772-7'),
  ('Ball','0-12345-98777-9'),
  ('Hat','0-12345-98711-6'),
  ('Hat','0-12345-98712-3'),
  ('Tee','0-12345-98465-1')`

SELECT 
    PRODUCT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN I = 1 THEN XNumber ELSE '' END) AS Xnumber1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN I = 2 THEN XNumber ELSE '' END) AS Xnumber2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN I = 3 THEN XNumber ELSE '' END) AS Xnumber3
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        PRODUCT, 
        XNumber, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY XNumber) AS I 
    FROM @T
    ) AS DATA
GROUP BY 
    PRODUCT

Comment: Thanks for the idea Stephen. The solution from Hogan worked for me so I'll move on.